# Redis mget using Lua script in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, lua

I am passing an array of keys. Here `keylist = ['KEY_100', 'KEY_101']` 
I want to get all the values of the keys. But I am getting an error saying this, `node_redis: Deprecated: The EVAL command contains a argument of type Array.`
There is an issue in github suggesting to use toString() and again Parse the value in the end. But I am satisfied with that ans. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Nodejs:

```
getDataLua (keylist) {
    console.log('lua keylist:', keylist)
    const getAsync = promisify(this.client.eval).bind(this.client)
    const reply = await getAsync(fs.readFileSync('./lib/test1.lua'), 1, keylist)
    console.log('reply', reply)
    return reply
  }
```

Lua Script:

```
local keys = redis.call('keys', KEYS[1])
local values = redis.call('mget', unpack(keys))
local keyValuePairs = {}
for i = 1, #keys do
  keyValuePairs[i] = .. values[i]
end
return keyValuePairs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
const reply = await getAsync(fs.readFileSync('./lib/test1.lua'), keylist.length, ...keylist);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.